# I closed the devtools connection to my browser page; how can I get it back?

Tags: reactjs, devtools

I was troubleshooting a reactjs web page using Edge with devtools.  By default, when there are javascript errors, the errors are shown in the running web browser tab with a black screen with (now that it's not showing I'm guessing from memory) red text.  When the code issues are fixed and saved, that error message goes away and the page shows up as coded.  Whenever the error page displays, the browser quickly flashes what appears to be the intended page but it's so fast I couldn't really catch what was showing and I was hoping to see something that would help in troubleshooting.

I never noticed it before tonight, after years of intermittent usage of devtools, but there's an "X" in the upper-right of that error display in the browser tab to close the error message.  I clicked the "X" so I could see what was behind it, hoping to see some partial rendering of my project page.  I didn't get what I wanted; the screen behind the error message was blank and now I can't get that error message to display again.  I have tried closing the tab, closing devtools, etc.  I've searched the documentation and the Internet and I can't even find a text description that seems to even describe the error display I'm talking about or any pictures or images in documentation or other articles about devtools that show the error message.

In one article I read, it talks about devtools disconnecting from the app due to certain error conditions in code.  And in that article, fixing the code restored the connection from devtools to the app.  I have no idea of that "disconnecting" is what is going on except I know it's not from an error in code since the devtools was working as intended until I pushed the "do not push this button" button.  I only point this part out because that concept of "connection" might be the terminology/function I'm looking for but I don't really know for sure.

Any idea how to restore that error display behavior?

---

Edit to update, I don't know what changed or what I did but when I checked it again this morning, the expected behavior is back again and the stack trace is showing in the browser.

Comment: Usually the console tab in browser's Developer Tool will also tell you similar error aside from the devtool from that shows prettier UI on the page. Can you -- 1. look into the Console in browser' Developer Tool, and 2. provide more info or screenshot of your problem? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Taiwei.  Yes, I am able to find the errors in the console and other views in the devtools and these other mechanisms are probably better than the in-browser view but I'd like to have the in-browser view, as well.  I checked it again this morning and now it is working again.  I have no idea what I did or what changed to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the project again this morning, I got the correct error stack trace in the browser.  I don't know what I did different to make it work again but it appears to be working now.